# Structure of synapse

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

When we study the structure of the chemical synapse, by default we come across Axo-dendritic synapse consisting of various cell adhesion molecules/receptors etc. (like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rndsystems.com%2Fresources%2Farticles%2Fsynaptic-proteins-and-receptors-schematic-rd-systems&psig=AOvVaw1vxnwMk4ZYuLg0L9yd0u-N&ust=1613789189625000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAYQjRxqFwoTCLCX7rP39O4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)). However, I was particularly interested in dendro-axonic synapses. Does the picture of synapse applies to every type of synapse or are we only aware of the axodendritic synapse? I mean, do the same cell adhesion or signalling molecules also present in dendro-axonic synapse? If yes, What could be their possible influence on passing action potential? I went through literature, but I couldn't find any focusing on subcellular structure and distribution at dendro-axonic synapses.

Comment: What do you mean by "dendro-axonic" synapse?

Comment: This classification is based on the type of connection. Here, dendrites connect with the axon (axon post-synaptic) I found few mentions in literature such as https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0006899379909417 and https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cne.901670204.